# What is that which is "within" in Luke 11:41?

Tags: greek, luke

Luke 11:41:

> But give that which is within as charity, and then all things are clean for you. (NASB)

What does the word "within" (ἐνόντα) mean in conjunction with "charity" (ἐλεημοσύνην)? How do you give what is within you as charity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luke 11:37-53 relates an incident where Jesus is eating at a pharisee's home.  The immediate context of V41 is reproduced below:

> **38** But the Pharisee was surprised to see that Jesus did not first wash before the meal.
>
> **39** “Now then,” said the Lord, “you Pharisees clean the outside of the cup and dish, but inside you are full of greed and wickedness.
> **40** You fools! Did not the One who made the outside make the inside as well? **41** But give as alms the things that are within you, and
> you will see that everything is clean for you.

Note that Jesus uses "the cup/dish" as a metaphor for a person and then distinguishes between the inside vs the outside.

- The "inside" consists of the person's motives and attitudes such as greed and wickedness [and selfishness] (v39)
- The "outside" consists of the show of pious works for which the pharisees were noted; and that these outward shows of piety were different from their internal selfishness.

Jesus contrasts the show of outward pious works with the hidden motives of greed and avarice internally of such people.  Jesus then prescribes a remedy - become generous to the poor from internal motives of real generosity and love, and then both the inside and outside of the cup/dish will be clean = righteous in this metaphor.

That is, if people (pharisees here) give from a true internal spirit of generosity, then their outward works will match their inward motives.  Or, in the the language of Jesus here, (V41), "So clean the inside by giving gifts to the poor, and you will be clean all over." (NLT)

Comment: Very enlightening answer - thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer indeed.